# Can stripe.js be loaded in non-blocking fashion?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Can stripe.js be deferred and used with some ready - callback that i can't find in the docs?

This is what i wanna do:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/" async></script>
```

And then in my app:

```
function stripeReadyHandler () {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I note that this QA post is from 2014 and is for `js.stripe.com/v2` and not (as of early 2019) `checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out, there's a standards compliant way to do this:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/" async onload="stripeReadyHandler()"></script>
```

and then:

```
function stripeReadyHandler () {
  //this will definitely do stuff ( if you're above IE9 of course
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Or, with JavaScript:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/';
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey(publishableKey);
  // do stuff
};
```

Comment: I used this because I have a content security policy that prevents me from using inline scripting.