# Jquery load and execute external script asynchronously then executing callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to load stripe asynchronously, after DOM is loaded, their provided sync code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I saw an answer on : [Can stripe.js be loaded in non-blocking fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715092/can-stripe-js-be-loaded-in-non-blocking-fashion) But it does not work well on my tests.

The only way I found is using jquery, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.getScript( "https://js.stripe.com/v2/", stripeReadyHandler() );
});
```

The problem is, as jQuery documentation itself says: *The callback is fired once the script has been loaded **but not necessarily executed**.*

How can I make sure the script is loaded after page load, and that the handler will be called only after it is loaded and executed?

Comment: Does the script initialize any global variables? If so you could simply check if the global variable has been initialized

Comment: it does instantiate the 'Stripe' object... can I have some sort of callback for that or do I have to set up a timeout to keep checking?

Comment: I would check the stripe js documentation to see if it fires any events when it's finished executing. If not a setInterval or settimeout should work fine.

Comment: are you looking for http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp ?